# Where should the business rules be implemented?

Tags: design-patterns, business-logic, architecture

1) Should them be implemented in a module over any set of their methods?
2) Should them be implemented in a special class where every method test a specific business rule?

Also... could you recommend me any good bibliography on the issue?

UPDATE:

> "A business rule is a rule of a business, company, or corporation. It is a rule that defines or constrains some aspect of business and always resolves to either true or false" [Wikipedia definition.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rule)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you'll have to have a clear definition of what a "business rule" is.  There are a bevy of candidates:

1. Information about your products.
2. Rules regarding sales that depend on time, location, customer, product, phase of the moon (aka closing date of the month), season, etc.
3. User roles (e.g., normal versus preferred customers, etc.)
4. Rules around accounts payable and receivable
5. GAAP rules

What exactly do you mean?  It's a vague question that can be quite large if you let it.

You have lots of choices as to where they go in your code:

1. Data driven, stored in databases
2. Expressions in a Rete rules engine.
3. Middle tier classes if you're writing OO.
4. Properties or configuration files if you're doing declarative programming.
5. Executable rules expressed in something like JavaScript.
6. In your ERP, MRP, A/P and A/R systems.
7. Fronted by web services that your apps compose together.

Do you see the problem you're opening up?  Your question implies that you have a well-defined problem and expect a simple, neat answer.  The truth is that it's a broad topic.

Comment: Actually you showed me an important step towards knowing different possibilities... that's partially what I was expecting!

Comment: I'm now using the definition stated at wikipedia... maybe you could update your answer accordingly.

Comment: "A business rule is a rule of a business, company, or corporation" - nothing more than a tautology.  See what that means at Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a generic question and hard to answer -- but I'd say take a look at [Behaviour Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_Driven_Development) as a way of keeping business rules at the heart of your development.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you investigate the MVC paradigm - Model View Controller.  There should be no business logic in the view, it should all be in the model.

Comment: Off focused answer. I'm not speaking about View layer. I'm only asking about any business component that has to validate business rules....

Comment: I'm not sure if it's "unfocused" - that paradigm describes a design wherein any "business component" would be a self-contained model, and as such is easy to test.

Comment: Overly simplistic, in my view.  Systems that aren't toys rarely fit all their logic so neatly in a handful of objects.

Comment: @duffymo: I am inclined to disagree - however, if the frameworks you are using do not easily allow the MVC paradigm, then indeed, you would be disinclined to use MVC for small toy projects. A case in point are toy MFC applications vs toy Cocoa applications. The latter trivially allows MVC style applications.

Comment: You keep talking about MVC is if that's all there was to rules - or system design, for that matter.  I know what MVC is, and the problem of business rules is about far more than that.  As a matter of fact, I'd say that a majority of business rules have nothing at all to do with view, so MVC should not apply.

Comment: All business rules have some sort of interface - however, rather than argue my answer, I suggest you refine your question.  Many responses to your question have been vague and generic, because your question is vague and generic.

Comment: I assume that Arafangion is addressing the OP, not me.  One more bit of info for him: I generally use Spring, which has a very good web MVC module.  Yet there are still legitimate questions about where business rules need to go.  Your point misses the mark by a wide margin.

Comment: Such questions are best asked specifically and explicitly.  The OP is too generic to assume that that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on multiple factors like

- should customer make changes to the rules?
- How often the rules change?
- Should updated rules be deployed without restarting the application?

If answer is YES to all of them above then a rules engine (drools, ilog etc) is what you are looking for to implement your rules

If your answer is NO then the alternative is to to model the rules in code keeping below in mind

- encapsulate 1 business rule in its own class so that it can be independently tested, customized and updated
- name the rule the way business mentions it (ubiquitous language)
- Learn about the specifiation pattern ([domain driven design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)). I think this way of expressing rules is very intuitive and explicit

E.g. copied from [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/03/02/ddd-the-specification-pattern.aspx)

```
EligibleForDiscountSpecification isEligibleForDiscountRule = new EligibleForDiscountSpecification();
isEligibleForDiscountRule .IsSatisfiedBy(customer)
```

Comment: When do you think Specification pattern should be used? When not to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Business Rules best practices state that the rules should be pluggable components. A minimalist approach would consist in coding them in a dedicated library, and proceed with Dependency Injection, or Reflection... Maybe you should investigate about Contracts Driven Development too, and look at [www.businessrulesgroup.org/brmanifesto.htm](http://www.businessrulesgroup.org/brmanifesto.htm) to begin.